# Calculating difference between various dates and results for each different date

Tags: python, datetime, time

Good day all,

I have various dates and then each date has test results.

Ie: date 1: result = 5
Date 2: result = 12 etc…

How do I compare the dates and results in python:
(current date - previous date) / (current result - prev result)

Keeping in mind I have at times 20 columns with different dates and results.

More info:

```
Df = pd.DataFrame{‘dates’: [date1, date2, date3, date4],
```

‘results’: [5,9,0,4]
}

To do the trend I will use the followinng formula:

Current result - prev result / current date - prev date

(9-5)/(date2-date1)
Get result
Then

(4-0)/(date4-date3)
Get result. Then trend all the results on a line plot.

I am able to do this for 2 dates, but have multiple dates with multiple results. In excel i do the calculation, but I would like to automate this. Just load dataset into pandas and  script does all the calculations.

Comment: please include specific data to work with.

Comment: Have you tried something? Are you working with pandas?

Comment: I have added some more details